# Restrict modification of public view

Tags: 2013, permissions, view, personalization

Here's a situation:
I have users that use a list.  They're allowed (and encouraged) to create personal views.  With this, I wanted to see if there was a way to keep these users from being able to modify existing public views?  There are a couple of users that make things difficult for the rest of the team, because they're constantly changing the default public view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably Users have set Edit Permissions, so change it to Contribute or create your own Permission level:

- Go to Site Settings > Site Permissions > Permission Levels (in ribbon) > Click on Edit, in the end click on "Copy this permissions" - remove Manage Lists, save as new Permissions Level, use this permission Level for users

**Don't edit original permission levels, always create new one.**

[image]